# Overlay Shapes in XML Drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

Is there a way to overlay a bitmap onto a shape in an XML drawable?  I want to put an icon on top of an oval shape.

Comment: Yes, there is. Use a LayerDrawable.

Comment: no,  you cannot do that in xml,  use `RoundedBitmapDrawable` or similar `Drawable` instead

Comment: @pskink So, [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) is totally wrong, *in your opinion*? Of course, **you can** mix xml drawables and bitmaps in a LayerDrawable.

Comment: @Rotwang OP want something like [this](https://muru-d.com/media/people/photos/profile-pic-sml.png.405x405_q85_border_width-15_circular.png), do that in xml

Comment: @pskink I'm actually looking for something simpler, just an icon on a gray circle

Comment: so you dont want to "round" your square image? if not, so yes, use <layer-list>

Comment: @pskink As I understood, the OP wants ` an oval shape` and overlay a bitmap to that.

Comment: @Rotwang it seems so, but he did not confirm that

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Bitmap overlayBitmapToCenter(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2) {
    int bitmap1Width = bitmap1.getWidth();
    int bitmap1Height = bitmap1.getHeight();
    int bitmap2Width = bitmap2.getWidth();
    int bitmap2Height = bitmap2.getHeight();

    float marginLeft = (float) (bitmap1Width * 0.5 - bitmap2Width * 0.5);
    float marginTop = (float) (bitmap1Height * 0.5 - bitmap2Height * 0.5);

    Bitmap overlayBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap1Width, bitmap1Height, bitmap1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlayBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, marginLeft, marginTop, null);
    return overlayBitmap;
}
```